# Input unnavailable with GCC

Tags: gcc, vim, neovim

I’ve been using the following script in my vimrc file for compiling and running C programs;

```vimscript
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F8> :w <bar> exec '!gcc '.shellescape('%').' -o '.shellescape('%:r').' && .\'.shellescape('%:r')<CR>
```

The issue is, if the program has an input function, when I run it, it doesn’t ask for inputs, it simply finishes and it shows

```
Press ENTER to continue
```

**Note:** This is on Windows 10—*I know*, but it’s my only option at the moment.

Comment: Try using the integrated terminal `:terminal`; ! In neovim is non-interactive. For building the program though I recommend `:make`.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm seeing it right, your keybinding executes the line immediately, after pressing `<F8>` due to the `<CR>` at the end of the line which represents your enter-key.
So you can remove it and use that:

```
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F8> :w <bar> exec '!gcc '.shellescape('%').' -o '.shellescape('%:r').' && .\'.shellescape('%:r')
```

Everytime when you press `<F8>` you should be prompted in the commandline and enter your arguments just as you'd do in the commandline.